# List in edit mode - certain cells won't display delete control

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

In certain scenarios, entering into edit mode makes the delete control (, i.e. red minus button on the left) appear selectively on certain cells of the list and not on others.

The expectation is that it should appear on all cells that are part of the `ForEach` block on which the `.onDelete()` modifier is applied.

### Steps to reproduce:

Here's one of the scenarios in which I'm encountering this problem (there are more scenarios, but they seem to be some variation of this one) -

1. Pick any two cells.
2. Swipe left on cell #1 (reveals destructive swipe action; edit mode
   becomes `.transient`).
3. Swipe left on cell #2 (restores cell #1 to it's usual state).
4. Swipe right on cell #2 (hides swipe action).
5. Wait for a brief second (edit mode becomes `.inactive`).
6. Press custom button to go into `.active` edit mode.
7. Notice that all cells except cell #1 display their delete control.

### Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pepBoys = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"]
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            editMode = editMode == .active ? .inactive : .active
        } label: {
            Text("Toggle edit mode")
        }
        
        List {
            ForEach(pepBoys, id: \.self) { pepBoy in
                Text(pepBoy)
                    /* this bit is optional - problem occurs with or without it
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                        Button(role: .destructive) {
                            pepBoys.removeAll {
                                $0 == pepBoy
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                        }
                    }
                    */
            }
            .onDelete { pepBoys.remove(atOffsets: $0) }
            .onMove { pepBoys.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1) }
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
    }
}
```

### Image:

[image: gif demo of the problem]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Could this be a SwiftUI bug?

I'm using the `.swipeActions()` API but this happens with the synthesized swipe action from just using `.onDelete()` too. Tested on iOS 15.

Comment: Can you post a GIF of what you are talking about? I am not sure I am following what you are saying.

Comment: Tried reproducing with a sim running iOS 15 and saw the same behavior with any of the cells. Super weird. Not sure if it's a bug or something to do with the editing state var...

Comment: @Yrb Added the GIF.